# Calculate occupancy given in rate and out rate

Tags: algorithm

You have a bucket. You don’t know how big the bucket is. You don’t know how much water is currently in the bucket, but you know the bucket isn’t overflowing and it has never overflowed.

You know the rate at which water flows into the bucket, which changes at different times of the day, but is never exactly zero. You also know the rate at which water flows out of the bucket from a spigot, which also changes over the day, but is never exactly zero.

There is a certain level of error with the meters that measure the inflow and outflow. We know this because the total volume of inflow is greater than outflow, but the bucket doesn’t overflow.

What algorithmic approach would be best for approximating the water that’s in the bucket at any given time?

What I have so far:

```
t: current time period    
Occ(t):  occupancy     
In(t): period rate in    
Out(t): period rate out    
Occ(t) = In(t) – Out(t) + Occ(t-1)
```

Problems:

1. When there’s never really a period when we can expect the bucket to have zero occupancy, we have to figure out a way to estimate an occupancy for a t = 0 (where t can be arbitrarily picked from the past data.) If there is some regularity to how the flow rates vary by day, is there any statistical way to calculate this?
2. Accounting for the error factor of In/Out ratio. Generally this amounts to finding the difference between in and out, dividing it by two, and adding the result to the deficient side while subtracting it from the excessive side. But this seems like a crude approximation which is subject to the condition of initial and final quantity, and any enhancement would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome in the *vast* world of numerical analysis. Check this out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: I'd look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter, but I'd also try hard to find even a poor estimate of the level, as given noise in the inflow and outflow measurements, you will face a steadily increasing cumulative error unless you can get some sort of estimate of the level.

Comment: The Kalman filter looks useful, thanks. I'm looking into the implementation details. Dan, the data is real, but the bucket is an analogy. In real life it's traffic data and occupancy problems that I'm working with.